# (How) Can you get current date in XSLT/XPath using .Net XPath processing

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

Seeing as MS are not implementing Xpath/XSL 2.0 and their XPath extension does not include a current-date() function, how do you achieve this within an XSLT?

NB. I don't have control of the calling code so I can't pass in as a parameter or set up a help DLL etc.

Thanks
Matt

Comment: It looks like you are restricting your resources...

Comment: From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms950808.aspx , there seems to be an effort to bring EXSLT into .Net XPath/XSLT through an extended XsltContext class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Received this feedback from MSDN Blogs forum. Posting here for completeness:

Hi Matt,

There are basically 3 ways of achieving what you need.

1. Pass the date as an external parameter (see details here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dfktf882(VS.80).aspx) – this is an ideal solution but from what you wrote it may not be possible
2. Use a script inside your stylesheet – here is an example

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
   xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
   xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
   xmlns:my="put-your-namespace-uri-here"               
   exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl my">

     <xsl:output method="xml"/>

     <msxsl:script language="C#" implements-prefix="my">
       public string Now(){
         return DateTime.Now.ToString("O");
       }
     </msxsl:script>

     <xsl:template match="/">
       <now>
         <xsl:value-of select="my:Now()" />
       </now>
     </xsl:template>
   </xsl:stylesheet>
   ```

   The caveat here is that if a stylesheet contains a script you should load it only once and reuse (for performance reasons it is recommended even if you don’t have a script). The reason for this is that every time you load an xslt stylesheet it will compile the script to a dynamically created assembly which cannot be then unloaded (the only way to unload them is to unload the whole appdomain). If your application does it very often then you can end up having OutOfMemoryException.
3. Use an extension object – similar to the above but you don’t have the problem with the dynamic assemblies. Here are some details on how to do this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xsl.xsltargumentlist.addextensionobject.aspx